# SAPUI5 Formatter is not called

Tags: xml, sapui5, formatter

I am trying to call a the formatter. e.g. to transform a text to uppercase. I have two formatters, one is in the controller and one is globally in the utils folder.

i tried to call both, but none is called. Can someone help me please :(?

I have a global formatter in utils folder:

```js
jQuery.sap.declare("my.app.util.Formatter");
my.app.util.Formatter = {

    toUpperCase: function(sStr) {
        return sStr.toUpperCase();
    }

};
```

and one formatter in my controller (i do the require `$.sap.require("my.app.util.Formatter");` as well):

```js
myControllerToUpperCaseFormatter : function(sStr) {
  console.log('I WILL DO NOTHING!');
  return sStr.toUpperCase();
}
```

my XML:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="my.app.view.XXX"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:c="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m">
<Page class="sapUiFioriObjectPage" title="Test">
    <content>

        <Button text="{path: 'MyModel>/name', formatter: 'my.app.util.Formatter.toUpperCase'}"></Button>

        <Button text="{path: 'MyModel>/name', formatter: '.myControllerToUpperCaseFormatter' }"></Button>

    </content>
</Page>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you specified, in the UI5 bootstrap, that you want support for "complex" binding syntax?

`data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"`

Answer (score 1):

Your binding doesn't look correct

`MyModel>/name` //  it states that name is a property at the root of the data property hierarchy.
Right Way:

```
<Button text="{path: 'MyModel>name', formatter: '.myControllerToUpperCaseFormatter' }"></Button>
```

Nevertheless, I too sometimes have faced this issue!

For some reason, when two or more parameters are used it started working.

Example:

```
<Button text="{parts:[{path:'MyModel>name'},{path:'MyModel>somethingElse'}],formatter: '.myControllerToUpperCaseFormatter' }"></Button>
```

Other Solution:

Looks like you are binding the data from UI controller.
If yes, format the data you want and then set it to model.

Comment: `MyModel>/name` doesn't imply a collection, it just states that name is a property at the root of the data property hierarchy.

Comment: The assumption that /name is a collection is wrong, that's all.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Comment of @qmacro in the first post solved it! :)

Answer (score 0):

`data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"` in the **index.html** is the reason why your complex bindings like formatter gets called.

Comment: `xx-bindingsyntax` is experimental. Better use `compatversion="edge"` which sets the binding syntax automatically to `"complex"`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41554735/5846045